# Passing `training=true` when using Tensorflow 2's Keras Functional API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

When operating in graph mode in TF1, I believe I needed to wire up `training=True` and `training=False` via feeddicts when I was using the functional-style API. What is the proper way to do this in TF2?

I believe this is automatically handled when using `tf.keras.Sequential`. For example, I don't need to specify `training` in the following example from the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate):

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu',
                           kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.02),
                           input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

# Model is the full model w/o custom layers
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_data, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)
loss, acc = model.evaluate(test_data)
print("Loss {:0.4f}, Accuracy {:0.4f}".format(loss, acc))
```

Can I also assume that keras automagically handles this when training with the functional api? Here is the same model, rewritten using the function api:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=((28,28,1)), name="input_image")
hid = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu',
                           kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.02),
                           input_shape=(28, 28, 1))(inputs)
hid = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D()(hid)
hid = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(hid)
hid = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(hid)
hid = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(hid)
hid = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(hid)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(hid)
model_fn = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

# Model is the full model w/o custom layers
model_fn.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model_fn.fit(train_data, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)
loss, acc = model_fn.evaluate(test_data)
print("Loss {:0.4f}, Accuracy {:0.4f}".format(loss, acc))
```

I'm unsure if `hid = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(hid)` needs to be `hid = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(hid, training)`?

A colab for these models can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/justincosentino/d36d66cddb1d606f72818c63d90d5147).

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to want to control the training flag, or are you asking if its needed at all?

Comment: I guess I would want to be able to set it in a forward pass on `model_fn()` (`tf.keras.Model#call`) so that BatchNormalization behaves correctly. I assume I would need to subclass model and define the forward pass call explicitly so that I can pass `training` to the BN invocation, similarly to the example in https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model.

I would also like to know if it is needed at all _when using `model_fn.fit()`_.

Comment: @cosentiyes: You mentioned *I believe this is automatically handled when using `tf.keras.Sequential`*. Are you sure this is true? Do you have any reference which proves that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I realized that there is a bug in the `BatchNormalization` documentation [1] where the `{{TRAINABLE_ATTRIBUTE_NOTE}}` isn't actually replaced with the intended note [2]:

**About setting `layer.trainable = False` on a `BatchNormalization` layer:**
  The meaning of setting `layer.trainable = False` is to freeze the layer,
  i.e. its internal state will not change during training:
  its trainable weights will not be updated
  during `fit()` or `train_on_batch()`, and its state updates will not be run.
  Usually, this does not necessarily mean that the layer is run in inference
  mode (which is normally controlled by the `training` argument that can
  be passed when calling a layer). "Frozen state" and "inference mode"
  are two separate concepts.

However, in the case of the `BatchNormalization` layer, **setting
  `trainable = False` on the layer means that the layer will be
  subsequently run in inference mode** (meaning that it will use
  the moving mean and the moving variance to normalize the current batch,
  rather than using the mean and variance of the current batch).
  This behavior has been introduced in TensorFlow 2.0, in order
  to enable `layer.trainable = False` to produce the most commonly
  expected behavior in the convnet fine-tuning use case.
  Note that:

- This behavior only occurs as of TensorFlow 2.0. In 1.*,
    setting `layer.trainable = False` would freeze the layer but would
    not switch it to inference mode.
- Setting `trainable` on an model containing other layers will
    recursively set the `trainable` value of all inner layers.
- If the value of the `trainable`
    attribute is changed after calling `compile()` on a model,
    the new value doesn't take effect for this model
    until `compile()` is called again.

[1] https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/BatchNormalization?version=stable

[2] https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/normalization_v2.py#L26-L65

Comment: Thanks for your question and answer, I'm looking exactly for the same. What about `Dropout` layer? It's a bit different as it's about switching on (training) and off (inference). Do you know if this is handled (somehow) by default or do you need to deal with it by yourself?

Answer (score 6):

As for the original broader question of whether you have to manually pass the `training` flag when using Keras Functional API, this example from the [official docs](https://keras.io/getting_started/intro_to_keras_for_researchers/#the-functional-api-for-modelbuilding) suggests that you **should not**:

```
# ...

x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
outputs = Linear(10)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

# ...

# You can pass a `training` argument in `__call__`
# (it will get passed down to the Dropout layer).
y = model(tf.ones((2, 16)), training=True)
```

Comment: I landed up here searching for an example like this. After that, i realized that i could make a simple test myself: https://colab.research.google.com/gist/jjclavijo/f216cb335fdd206bf68238553f9658b0/scratchpad.ipynb . May be it is a good complement to the answer.